# What is the best way to find elements from an array in another array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have a function buildList with an array of numbers in argument.
I also have 11 elements which are numbers and i want to know if these elements exists in the array and if one element doesn't exist i push it in another array.

Actually it looks like that:

```
public static buildList(numbers[]) {
const newArray= [];
    if (numbers.find(element => element === ELEMENT_ONE) === undefined ) {
      newArray.push(ELEMENT_ONE);
    }
    if (numbers.find(element => element === ELEMENT_TWO) === undefined ) {
      newArray.push(ELEMENT_TWO);
    }
    ....
}
```

My current intuition was to create a new array with the 11 elements and do a for each but i'm not pretty sure the performance will be better...
Is there any way to improve this code ? because i do the same things for the 11 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static buildList(numbers[]) {
      const newArray = [];
      elevenElements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

// Use this logic to filter elements.
      newArray = elevenElements.filter(d => !numbers.includes(d))
    }
```

Comment: Prints just an error: SyntaxError: unexpected token: 'static'. FF here.

Comment: @ceving I have just written the logic requested by the user.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function buildList(numbers) {
  let newArray = [];
  elevenElements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

  // Use this logic to filter elements.
  newArray = elevenElements.filter(d => numbers.some(y => y === d))
  return newArray;
}

const result=buildList([1, 8, 9]);
console.log(result)
```